# KeyCloak dockerfile Configuration and running with Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, dockerfile, containers, keycloak

Hello I got the following DockerFile from the official site:

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest as builder

# Enable health and metrics support
ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true

# Configure a database vendor
ENV KC_DB=mysql

WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
# for demonstration purposes only, please make sure to use proper certificates in production instead
RUN keytool -genkeypair -storepass password -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=server" -alias server -ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0>RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

# Change these values to point to a running MySQL instance
ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keyCloak
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=root
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=root
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=localhost
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]
```

Its running well and building the appropriate image but when I try run it throught a container with this command:

```
docker run --name keycloakNew -p 8448:8443 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin my-keycloak-image start --optimized
```

It brings error: Unknown option: '--optimized'
Try 'kc.sh start --help' for more information on the available options.
Anyone got any Idea what is this and how to resolve the issue?
Maybe the problem is that keycloak got newer version and changed the Dockerfile?

I did the above and the result was this i mentioned

Comment: probably the `--optimized` argument is deprecated, check by running `docker run -it --rm --name keycloakNew -p 8448:8443 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin my-keycloak-image start --help`

Comment: no the problem is not with the optimized. The problem is that it needs extra commands to run? or something like that?    Something is wrong with the kc.sh

Comment: that seems to be the problem `Unknown option: '--optimized' `, if you run the command with `--help` you should see the arguments it accepts, probably there is no `--optimized`

Comment: i did run it and gives me a list of something like this :  Start the server.

Usage:

kc.sh start [OPTIONS]

Use this command to run the server in production.         And many more so maybe it need changes in my Dockerfile?

Comment: But, if you launch without `--optimized` ?